# Simple KnockoutJS nested foreach not working

Tags: knockout.js, foreach, nested

This works:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: roles, as: 'role' }">
    <h3 data-bind="text: role.NamePlural"></h3>
</div>

<div data-bind="foreach: { data: genders, as: 'gender' }">
    <h4 data-bind="text: gender.NamePlural"></h4>
</div>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: roles, as: 'role' }">
    <h3 data-bind="text: role.NamePlural"></h3>
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: genders, as: 'gender' }">
        <h4 data-bind="text: gender.NamePlural"></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

I only get the first `role`, i.e. it breaks when it starts the nested `foreach` loop. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: This is the data I'm using

```
[{"Id":1,
  "Name":"Athlete",
  "NamePlural":"Athletes"},
 {"Id":2,
  "Name":"Referee",
  "NamePlural":"Referees"},
 {"Id":3,
  "Name":"Coach",
  "NamePlural":"Coaches"}]

[{"Id":1,
  "Name":"Female",
  "NamePlural":"Women"},
 {"Id":2,
  "Name":"Male",
  "NamePlural":"Men"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your first code work, `roles` and `genders` are in the one level in your ViewModel. But in your second code you try to use `genders` as field of `role`.
You could rewrite it as:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: roles, as: 'role' }">
    <h3 data-bind="text: role.NamePlural"></h3>
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: $root.genders, as: 'gender' }">
        <h4 data-bind="text: gender.NamePlural"></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or use `$parent` instead of `$root` if your model have more nested layers.

Comment: Ahh of course, I knew it was something simple ;) Thank you!